# How to use bash commands with withEnv in Jenkins Scripted Pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In Jenkins declarative pipelines, it is quite easy to set an environment variable as the result of a bash command in the following manner.

For example, the values of `USERNAME`, `UID` and `GID` are set as the result of their respective bash commands.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'master'
            customWorkspace "some/path"
        }
    }
    environment {
        USERNAME = sh(script:"whoami", returnStdout: true).trim()
        UID = sh(script:"id -u", returnStdout: true).trim()
        GID = sh(script:"id -g", returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
```

How do I do the equivalent when using Jenkins scripted pipelines?

For example, say I have the following `node` block, what do I put inside `withEnv` to achieve the same result? The objective is so that `USERNAME`, `UID` and `GID` contain the username, uid and gid of the user on my `external-test-server` node.

```
node('external-test-server') {
    stage("Test") {
        withEnv([
            // Note that the following does not work and is meant to illustrate what my objective is
            'USERNAME=${sh(script:"whoami", returnStdout: true).trim()}',
            'UID=${sh(script:"id -u", returnStdout: true).trim()}',
            'GID=${sh(script:"id -g", returnStdout: true).trim()}'
        ]) {
            dir("../some_path") {
                sh "pwd"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

I also need to be sure that the environment variables in `node('external-test-server')` must override previously set environment variables outside the node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `withEnv` block is not working due to missing quotes, as per below should work

```
node {
    
    //initiated some values to make sure withEnv block overrides these
    env.USERNAME = "testUser"
    env.UID = "99"
    env.GID = "99"
    
    stage("Test") {
        withEnv([
            // This should now work
            "USERNAME=${sh(script:"whoami", returnStdout: true).trim()}",
            "UID=${sh(script:"id -u", returnStdout: true).trim()}",
            "GID=${sh(script:"id -g", returnStdout: true).trim()}"
        ]) {
            dir("myNewPath") {
                println USERNAME
                println UID
                println GID
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, my pipeline has the `USERNAME` environment variable already set and in `node('external-test-server')`, I want the `USERNAME` environment variable to override the "outside" `USERNAME` environment variable. I tried your suggestion of using `env.USERNAME` in my node; however, it didn't seem to override the original `USERNAME` environment variable.

Comment: I see what you mean, let me edit my answer, in that case it is only a matter of quotes, I believe